# Fabric js Image Filters Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to add Filters in Fabric js, my images are very heavy to apply the filters

How can is get the call back function for filter ?

As i want to show the loader till process is going on, i didn't get any property to set the loader till applying the image filters

Please help me out for the same.

Comment: can you show me code which you need to put loader. so i can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fabric method `applyFilters` accepts one argument and it is a callback (`obj` is just a fabric object):

```
function applyFilter(index, filter) {;
    obj.filters[index] = filter;
    obj.applyFilters(function () {
        console.log('this is the callback!');
        canvas.renderAll();
     });
 }
```

edit: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104283/show-loading-screen-while-filter-is-being-applied/30106267#30106267) has instructions for a loading screen using jQuery