# Show loading screen while filter is being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

Applying a filter to an image object that occupies the whole canvas can take a couple seconds with larger images and I want to display a loading screen while this is happening but the `.show()` method isn't firing until after the filter has been applied.

Current method that applies the filter:

```
applyFilter: function (index, filter) {
    var obj = designer.baseImage,
        $loading = $('#loading-canvas');

    console.log('show loading');
    $loading.show();

    obj.filters[index] = filter;

    obj.applyFilters(function () {
        console.log('hide loading');
        $loading.hide();
        designer.canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

When the method is called (on click) 'show loading' is logged to the console immediately. The loading div is not displayed until the filter has been applied, at which point the loading screen flashes up, goes away, and 'hide loading' is logged to the console. Any ideas why the loading screen isn't displayed when 'show loading' is logged to the console?

Edit: The loading screen's sole purpose so to indicate to the user that something is happening

Comment: Javascript is single thread language. You should try e.g: `$loading.show(0, function(){obj.filters[index] = filter; //all rest of filters logic here});`

Comment: One question to ask design-wise: Does the user need to see the load progress, or just that something is happening? For many people the answer is the former out of sheer simplicity, but it depends on your design.

Comment: @MariM they don't "need" to see the loading progress, the loading screen is to indicate that something is happening

Comment: I think I misunderstood: are you showing a loading bar (i.e. 45%) or just a screen that says something is happening?

Comment: No progress bar, it's simple a div positioned absolutely over the canvas with a spinner to indicate something is happening @MariM

Comment: Excellent, that's what I like to hear! Heed A. Wolff's words then with using complete callback functions to ensure the order of events is maintained.

Comment: @A.Wolff after tinkering it seems to be some sort of timing issue, setting the first argument to 'fast' works and 'slow' works even better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@A.Wolff was super close but it appeared to be a timing issue? Here's my solution:

```
applyFilter: function (index, filter) {
    var obj = designer.baseImage,
        $loading = $('#loading-canvas');

    $loading.show('slow', function () {
        obj.filters[index] = filter;

        obj.applyFilters(function () {
            $loading.hide();
            designer.canvas.renderAll();
        });
    });        
}
```

The original solution didn't work with `show()`'s first argument being 0, worked better with 'fast' and works perfectly with 'slow'.

Answer (score 0):

I think @A wolff is right, you may use

```
$(".btnDoStuff").click(function () {
        $(".loading").show(function(){
            //dosomestuff
            //remove for Loop, it is just to demonstrate  that some code          is taking time
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                var j = i + 1;
            }
            $(".loading").hide();
        });
    });
```

however you may also use window.setTimeout